# C# about opening a bitmap file to display in winform

Tags: c#, winforms

Below is the way I write the coding to open a file to display on the picture box after I click button1:

```
        OpenFileDialog dlg = new OpenFileDialog();
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            dlg.Filter = "Image (*bmp)|*.bmp|All Files|*.*";
            SetLogo = 0;

            if (dlg.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {

               this.pictureBox1.Image = (System.Drawing.Bitmap)Image.FromFile(dlg.FileName);

               int nMaxBitmapHeigth = 800;
               int nMaxBitmapWidth = 950;
                string strOrgFullPath = dlg.FileName;

                System.Drawing.Bitmap bmpNew = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(strOrgFullPath);
                System.Drawing.Bitmap bmpOrg = null;

          // after this is the code for resizing the image to show on another picture box.
        }
```

After open the image to display in the picture box, I can select the size of the image from the combobox44:

```
private void comboBox44_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int nMaxBitmapHeigth = 800;
    int nMaxBitmapWidth = 950;

    System.Drawing.Bitmap bmpNew = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(dlg.FileName);
    System.Drawing.Bitmap bmpOrg = null;

// after this is the code for resizing the image to show on another picture box.
}
```

Both coding on button1 and combobox44 is about the same just that button1 enable the user to choose the image file from the dialog box and combobox44 will use back the image from button1.

But there's an error after compiling. The error refers to this line "System.Drawing.Bitmap bmpNew = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(dlg.FileName);" on combobox44. The error message is "The path is not of a legal form." What's wrong? Why can't I use the image from button1?

Comment: What is in `dlg.FileName`? This is probably getting fired before you have selected a file. (An `OpenFileDialog` is a horrible place to store a path for any length of time beyond just after OK is pressed, and I'm not sure it's that great an idea to just keep it around in memory once you're through with it)

Comment: I guess dlg.Filename is emtpy in combobox44_SelectedIndex. Attach a debuigger and set a breakpoint (F9) to verify.

Comment: dlg.Filename is the same as button1. I'm thinking of what button1 choose will be use in combobox44. Can I write like that?

Comment: I thought dlg.Filename is global and can be use anywhere? Or is it not?

Comment: If I press button1 first only then I press comboBox44 it is fine. If I press combobox44 first it will have the error.

Answer (score 3):

Take a image directly from `picturebox1` you don't need to load image from file because you already loaded image for `picurebox1`

```
 private void comboBox44_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int nMaxBitmapHeigth = 800;
        int nMaxBitmapWidth = 950;

        if (this.pictureBox1.Image != null)
        {
            System.Drawing.Bitmap bmpNew = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(this.pictureBox1.Image, new System.Drawing.Size(nMaxBitmapHeigth, nMaxBitmapWidth));
            System.Drawing.Bitmap bmpOrg = null;     
        }
        // after this is the code for resizing the image to show on another picture box.
    }
```

Comment: +1 As long as you're not replacing the image in `picturebox1` after resizing at least. Otherwise you'll lose information if you resize small then big again.

Comment: @lc. yes you are right but he can take its information to another variable if he require it ..thanks

Comment: Yes I think keeping the original bitmap in memory is the best solution, whether in the picturebox or somewhere else.

Comment: Is it that I have to assign something to dlg.FileName when Form1_Load? If not, it will be empty when I press combobox44 and the error will appear.

Comment: yes it is empty but if I press combobox44 first, the error will appear because of it being empty.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to correct the code as follows:

```
    string strOrgFullPath = "";
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dlg.Filter = "Image (*bmp)|*.bmp|All Files|*.*";
        SetLogo = 0;

        if (dlg.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {

           this.pictureBox1.Image = (System.Drawing.Bitmap)Image.FromFile(dlg.FileName);

           int nMaxBitmapHeigth = 800;
           int nMaxBitmapWidth = 950;
            strOrgFullPath = dlg.FileName;

            System.Drawing.Bitmap bmpNew = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(strOrgFullPath);
            System.Drawing.Bitmap bmpOrg = null;

      // after this is the code for resizing the image to show on another picture box.
    }


    private void comboBox44_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int nMaxBitmapHeigth = 800;
        int nMaxBitmapWidth = 950;

        System.Drawing.Bitmap bmpNew = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(strOrgFullPath);
        System.Drawing.Bitmap bmpOrg = null;

    // after this is the code for resizing the image to show on another picture box.
    }

   Try, Best of luck
```

Comment: check `strOrgFullPath` when the event is getting fired. It's probably still empty.

Comment: Yes, I originally put comboBox44.SelectedIndex = 0; in Form1_Load. I think when Form1 load it detected the index change in combobox44 and run comboBox44_SelectedIndexChanged routine but find out that strOrgFullPath is empty. When I deleted comboBox44.SelectedIndex = 0; in Form1_Load, it is fine already.

Comment: Is it that the dlg.FileName from comboBox44 cannot be empty? Must have something?

Comment: If I press button1 first only then I press comboBox44 it is fine. If I press combobox44 first it will have the error.

Comment: @Coolguy, you have to maintain this flow: 1st button1 and then comboBox44, or you can disable comboBox44 till user doesn't press button1